# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I have changed the variable limit for java in environmental factors several times, I've adjusted maximum server ram usage in run.bat and still no luck.
Three different launches at different values include

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -Xmx4000M -Xms512M -jar C:\Users\cavem\OneDrive\Desktop\RLCraft+Server+Pack+1.12.2+-+Beta+v2.8.2\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4000M
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Could not reserve enough space for 4096000KB object heap

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -Xmx4000M -Xms512M -jar C:\Users\cavem\OneDrive\Desktop\RLCraft+Server+Pack+1.12.2+-+Beta+v2.8.2\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4100M
> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4100M
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -Xmx4000M -Xms512M -jar C:\Users\cavem\OneDrive\Desktop\RLCraft+Server+Pack+1.12.2+-+Beta+v2.8.2\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4000M
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Could not reserve enough space for 4096000KB object heap

If I give the program to much memory it doesn't start, if I give it to little it doesn't start. Any ideas as to what my problem may be? I changed the file to include complete location after receiving errors regarding not being able to find the file upon booting the server (running java and run.bat in administrator hasn't helped either).

Comment: Are you using 32-bit Java or 64-bit Java?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a 32-bit JVM, install a 64-bit JVM will work.